Using elimination theory to get single equation for trivariate quadratics
Let for $k\in\{1,2,3\}$
$$f_k(x,y,z)=a_kx^{2}+b_ky^{2}+c_kz^{2}+d_kxy+e_kxz+f_kyz+g_kx+h_ky+i_kz+j_k$$
be three general trivariate quadratics? How to reduce to univariate polynomial with common roots using elimination theory with linear operations?

In M2
S=QQ[x,y,z,w,MonomialOrder=>Lex]
Q1=random(2,S)
Q2=random(2,S)
Q3=random(2,S)
I=ideal(Q1,Q2,Q3)
gens gb I

And you’ll get your eight points in 3-space as most likely the first element is a binary octic in $z,w$ you can solve as a univariate octic in $\frac{z}{w}$.

what is w? This is trivariate...

I homogenized @Turbo. It’s still three quadrics in 3-space.

Is this mathematica?

@Turbo The full name is Macaulay2. Try it online
